# Identation using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I want to know how you would approach a problem where you need to indent properly a text(containing java code) by reading it from a file, using recursion. The original output would be without any
 tabs.

That's the goal:[image]

This is the code but I need to adapt it to read from a textfile:

```
void indent( int m, int n )
{
  System.out.println( m ); // Forward Printing

  if ( m < n )
  {
    indent( m + 1, n );
    System.out.println( m ); // Backward Printing
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `astyle`, `indent` or an `ide`. Most (all), of which can do that.

Comment: @Elliott Has to be recursion

Comment: What have you tried (show a [mcve]) ? Where are you stuck, what's the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the algorithm can be like...

```
function indent(theText, indentCharCount) {
   for each character of the text...
      if it is an end-of-line character...
         concatenate spaces to return string using indentCharCount
      else if it is a '{' character...
         scan ahead through characters to find matching '}' character
         recursively call indent() function passing...
            characters between { and } for 'theText' param
            indentCharCount+2 for 'indentCharCount' param
         concatenate return value of indent() to return string
         set loop index so that the next character will be the matched '}'
      else (it's some other character)
         concatenate character to return string
   return the concatenated string
}
```

I didn't want to write out all the code in Java. If you are doing a homework assignment, I'd rather you learn something! But that's a basic recursive algorithm that I believe fits your question.

Comment: If `theText` is an instance of `Reader` you don't need to scan ahead because when the recursive call returns the Reader will be at the character that comes after the closing bracket.

Comment: Very helpful sir! I'm gonna try to implement it.